# add labels and customize nodes in plotly sankey diagram

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to customize a sankey diagram done with pyplot. I would simply like to make some nodes invisible (e.g. transparent) and add some labels to the connection between nodes.

I modified slightly the code given as an example in the website, without much success. The node properties seem to be the same for all the same. Adding a label to the links does not modify the output.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
data = dict(
type='sankey',
node = dict(
  pad = 15,
  thickness = 20,
  line = dict(
    color = "black",
    width = 0.5
  ),
  label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],

  color = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
  "white", "white"]),#attempt to make it less visible

link = dict(
  source = [0,1,0,2,3,3],
  target = [2,3,3,4,4,5],
  value = [8,4,2,8,4,2],
  # attempt to add labels
  label= [8,4,2,8,4,2]))

layout =  dict(
title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
font = dict(
  size = 10
 )
 )

fig = dict(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Any suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add annotations for each of the link labels, the problem is, even if you add label to the links, it will get shown only on hover! below is an example of added annotations for your reference!

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode()
import numpy as np

data = dict(
type='sankey',
node = dict(
  pad = 15,
  thickness = 20,
  line = dict(
    color = "black",
    width = 0.5
  ),
  label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],

  color = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
  "gray", "white"]),#attempt to make it less visible

link = dict(
  source = [0,1,0,2,3,3],
  target = [2,3,3,4,4,5],
  value = [8,4,2,8,4,2],
  # attempt to add labels
  label= [8,4,2,8,4,2]))

layout =  dict(
title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
font = dict(
  size = 10
 ),
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=0.25,
            y=0.75,
            text='8',
            showarrow=False
        ),
        dict(
            x=0.75,
            y=0.25,
            text='4',
            showarrow=False
        )
    ]
 )

fig = dict(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```